# Can db corruption occur from power loss even with battery backed write cache?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

Datacenter power outage and we are awaiting restore. Our database server has battery backed write cache. Does that completely eliminate the chances of db corruption from primary power loss?

Comment: You won't ever get a 100% guarantee, but chances for data corruption or data loss are minimized if you use a (properly sized!) BBU and cache on your controllers. Different BBU and controller sizes mean different lengths of bridgeable external power loss, from minutes to hours to days.

Comment: Not if the disks have write caching enabled. You don't provide information about the hardware, but most decent hardware vendors disable disk write caching when attached to a raid controller.

Answer (score 0):

Completely? No. Hardware or software failures of the cache are still possible. Batteries or NAND storage can fail. Some systems are only designed for hours to days of durability when the power is off.

Although, a properly working cache will not lose data due to power loss. Also, a cache that properly degrades to write through when power loss protection is not present has a relatively small amount of data at risk.

---

Many databases should have the means to meet durability and point in time recovery requirements, whatever the underlying storage. For SQL Server, this is the transaction log and the recovery operations it enables. Verifying transaction recovery happened when starting back up is probably a good idea, even if the storage did emergency power off successfully.